# Compute a transformation law for k-tensor field

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Let $A$ be a smooth covariant $k$-tensor field on a smooth manifold $M$. In two overlapping charts $(U, x^i)$ and $(U, \tilde{x}^i)$ I can write $A$ using the these local coordinates as
$A = A_{i_1 ... i_k}dx^{i_1}\otimes ...\otimes dx^{i_k} = \tilde{A}_{j_1 ... j_k}d\tilde{x}^{j_1}\otimes ... \otimes d\tilde{x}^{j_k}$. I need to compute a transformation law to express $A_{i_1...i_k}$ in terms of $\tilde{A}_{i_1...i_k}$. I am really lost in the notation here and not sure what to do. I know that $A_{i_1...i_k} = A(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i_1}}, ... , \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i_k}})$, and the chain rule tells me that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i_l}} = \frac{\partial \tilde{x^{j_r}}}{\partial x^{i_l}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^{j_r}}$. But how can I use this to answer the question? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Literally plug the basis vectors into $A$, substitute your chain rule results, and use multilinearity of the tensor product.

Comment: $$A(\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i})=\bar{A}_kd\bar{x}^k(\frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{x}^j})=\bar{A}_k\frac{\partial \bar{x}^j}{\partial x^i}\delta^k_j=\bar{A}_k\frac{\partial \bar{x}^k}{\partial x^i}=A_i$$

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks! I'm glad it is as simple as it seems :)